# Is /etc/ssh/sshd_config supporting inline comments and multiple key / value within the same line?

Tags: bash, unix, sshd

I've to write an  small script to modify `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` if this file is not matching with my checklist.

For examples I've to check below entries are matched, if not I need to replace with below entires:

```
Banner  /etc/motd  
GatewayPorts no   
KeyRegenerationInterval 3600  
LoginGraceTime 120  
LogLevel INFO    
PermitEmptyPasswords No    
PermitRootLogin No
```

1. Is `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` will be always like: One entry in a line like above or can it be any uses delimiter (`Banner /etc/motd, GatewayPorts no`)?
2. Can comments can be anywhere in line (like C programming) or it should start at beginning of the line with `#`?

Answer (score 10):

From the [`sshd_config(5)`](https://linux.die.net/man/5/sshd_config) man page (emphasis mine):

> The file contains keyword-argument pairs, **one per line**.  Lines **starting with ‘#’** and empty lines are interpreted as comments.

Answer (score 3):

Part of answer was given, but does not answer everything, so:

From [`sshd_config(5)`](https://linux.die.net/man/5/sshd_config):

> [`sshd(8)`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/sshd) reads configuration data from /etc/ssh/sshd_config (or the
>   file specified with -f on the command line). **The file contains**
>   **keyword-argument pairs, one per line**. **Lines starting with '#' and**
>   **empty lines are interpreted as comments**. Arguments may optionally be
>   enclosed in double quotes (") in order to represent arguments
>   containing spaces.

1. Yes, it would always been like `KeyWord: value` and never `KeyWord1: value1, KeyWord2: value2`. (*The file contains keyword-argument pairs, one per line*)
2. It seems yes, it supports inline comments even if no one doc explicit this (so, you may avoid it). You can run `sshd -T` to validate your config and see it in action.

Answer (score 1):

While only one keyword / value is supported per line, as OpenSSH v8.5 [3/2021], both sshd_config and ssh_config have been updated to support tailing comments.

Example:

```
# This is a valid comment
keyword value # So is this
```

Though as of v9.1, the man pages are still out of date.

Ref: [Bug 2320 - end-of-line comments work in sshd_config but not in ssh_config](https://bugzilla.mindrot.org/show_bug.cgi?id=2320)

Answer (score 0):

So, the 2023 answer is: **It is supported**, but only if your SSH agent is [**v8.5**](https://bugzilla.mindrot.org/show_bug.cgi?id=2320) or above.

Run `ssh -V` to check your version.

```
ssh -V
OpenSSH_9.0p1, LibreSSL 3.3.6
```