# ssh hostname suggestion(completion) feature not working

Tags: ssh, zsh

im using ssh with config files on zsh(5.8)/wsl2.

i made additional config files and included them in `config` file.
ssh feature works fine. but when i type the ssh command with hostname, hostname suggestion feature is working conditionally

- suggestion feature works fine when i type the hostname that in `config` file
- but not work when type the hostname that in `Included config` file( but ssh feature works fine.)

here's are my config file and included config files

###### `config` in ~/.ssh/

```
Include ~/.ssh/config_a # hosts of a
Include ~/.ssh/config_b # hosts of b

# myhost
Host my_host1
...(skip)
```

###### `config_a` ... additional config files in same path

```
# in a
Host a_host1
...(skip)
```

###### tried commands.

```bash
ssh my_ # and press `tab`, suggestion work.
ssh a_ # and press `tab`, suggestion didnt work.

ssh a_host1 # ssh work.
```

if merge them into one file then suggestion works around all hosts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

zsh problem. solved it by removing tail comments in `Include ...` lines.

```
Include ~/.ssh/config_a 
Include ~/.ssh/config_b

# myhost
Host my_host1
...(skip)
```

OpenSSH supports the end of line comments. so, it has nothing to do with.

---

ref.

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/74759246/77259637
- [zsh sshdconfig completion codes](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh/blob/master/Completion/Unix/Type/_ssh_hosts)

---

additionally, i checked both bash and zsh.
 in bash, completion(suggestion) works fine.